# Can we associate materials with their phases (e.g. fluid or solid)?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

Since any material can change its phase as demonstrated in its phase diagram.

*Should we consider (for example) water as a fluid?*

Or in this example:

> In physics, a fluid is a substance that continually deforms (flows) under an applied shear stress. -- [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid)

Fluids are associated with the substance. Shouldn't it be:

"A fluid is a word which can describe any substance **at any instance of time only if** it can flow under an applied shear stress **at this particular instance of time**."

Comment: It assumes normal athmospheric conditions at the earth surface

Comment: Depending on the conditions, some materials can pass directly from the solid to the gas phase, it's called sublimation.

Comment: Water is also used as a name for the fluid state of H2O, so, it is not wrong. The frozen is called ice and gaseous is called steam. Those who do not assume this, they always refer to it as liquid water, rather than saying just water.

Answer (score 1):

The question in the title is false. Some materials may not exist in a fluid state because they undergo (irreversible) chemical change before becoming liquid or gaseous. What is the melting point of wood?

the text shows an unclear question about when to assume that water is a liquid (water is a bad example because we have different words for different phases)

Answer (score 0):

You asked - *Can any material be a fluid?*

Yes all types of matter have a melting point and can attain a fluid phase.

You said - *Please find mistakes in the following (if found):*

This statement would be better stated as follows.

Please point out any mistakes in the following statements and questions that follow.

Your Statement -

*Since any material can change its phase to a gaseous, supercritical, liquid or fluid state any material can be considered as a fluid, so it is wrong to say e.g. water is a fluid when speaking generally.*

First of all this is worded incorrectly and is not considered complete. It is also a run on sentence. If I understand you correctly it probably needs to be broken down into a correct and complete statement and a separate question.

Perhaps you should have stated it the following manner.

*Since any material's state can be changed to a plasma, gas, liquid or solid all materials can be considered to have a fluid state. Is it then wrong to say, for example, water is a fluid when speaking generally.*

The name water infers its state, at 1 atmosphere and room temperature, is a fluid. So it is redundant to say water is a fluid. Not necessary.

Also it is better to say state of matter rather then phase. The term phase is sometimes used as a synonym for state of matter, but a system can contain several immiscible phases of the same state of matter.

Comment: Elements are a particular class of materials. It's quite limiting to start from there.

Comment: Changed to matter

Comment: thanks but please explain "a system can contain several immiscible phases of the same state of matter."

Comment: Check out these links   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_(matter)                                   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiphasic_liquid

Answer (score 0):

Any material can be modeled as a fluid.  But this does add a good deal of error into you calculations.  For example, in some GR computational simulations a neutron star is modeled as a hydrodynamic fluid.  While physically incorrect, this simplified model allows us to make some basic results which are a first step to a correct physical model.  We sometime refer to this as a zeroth order approximation.

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE and thank you for your answer :) Do you think you could elaborate a bit on the difference between modelling assumptions and reality?

Comment: Computationally we are not able to accurately model a neutron star.  There is simply too much going on to model in a reasonable amount of time.  So in computational general relativity, we treat the star as a TOV star.  This ignores all of the nuclear interactions, neutrino transport, etc.  It is simply treated as a high density fluid.  We know it is wrong but we can answer some questions this way.  These models are good up to a point.  And as long as they match some component of nature they can be used until we learn to refine the model.  We have at least figured out gravitational radiation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "any" material, as plasmas are a bit more difficult to classify.  Other than that, in my opinion, a fluid is any material that doesn't have a definite shape if it is not in a container.  This means that air is a fluid (and other gases), water is a fluid (and other liquids), and in the chemical engineering world, solids can be a fluid when dealing with small particulate solids with air blowing upwards through them (e.g., a fluidized bed).  Another solids application involves transport of small solid particles (typically plastic beads) through pipelines by using air to fluidize them, or finely ground coal dispersed in water and pumped through pipelines fast enough to allow turbulent flow to keep the particles in suspension.  Note that for the fluidized bed applications, the solid does NOT have to be melted.

Answer (score -1):

You have a jump from specific to general there. Water is the name we give to the fluid form of hydrogen dioxide. When hydrogen dioxide is between 0 and 100 Celsius it is fluid. Your argument is analogous to saying "lava is hot but any matter can be hot so it is wrong to say lava is hot generally".

By purely linguistic definition, water is always a fluid. When it stops being fluid it is either ice or steam and no longer water. However all three are hydrogen dioxide.

Comment: *"hydrogen dioxide"*: you mean dihydrogen oxide - $\mathrm{H_2O}$.

Comment: whoops, I do mean that, long day! Thanks for the correction!

Comment: You're also neglecting pressure: water can be liquid at temperatures much higher and 100 C and lower than 0 C. It's a poor answer. The term 'water' isn't 'purely linguistically defined': chemists really don't care if $\mathrm{H_2O}$ is liquid, vapour or solid.

Comment: Again correct! I suppose in my rush to get to the point of the question I neglected a lot of important generality. I am confused by your last sentence though. Isn't water strictly H20 in the fluid phase? If you had a high enough pressure that you looked at some H20 at 70 Celsius and it was a solid, surely you would still call it ice, or at the very least frozen water? My idea in referring to "pure linguistic definition" is that it is very easy to conflate terms for similar but different things, and I think the source of Ahmed's confusion lay in vocabulary.

Comment: Just look at pressurised water reactors (PWR) (e.g.): water is much hotter than 100 C but perfectly liquid. Ahmed's confusion maybe linguistic but it's for *us to clear that up!*, not to add to it.

Comment: "Water is the name we give to the fluid form" that sentence made things clear for me, but I wonder if there is any material that has the same name in all of its phases

Comment: Ahmed - Most materials do! Water is so ubiquitous in all its forms that we have given it a name for each of its phases. However you'll notice that we call liquid nitrogen... liquid nitrogen! The same is true of liquid iron, or liquid, gaseous, or solid anything you can imagine. Even (god forbid) liquid Ahmed! The addition of liquid, solid, or gaseous to the name of a material only designates the behavior of the constituents of that material in it's current environment, but it's those constituents that determine what the material is.